# Data-trigger conflicts with fancybox

Tags: javascript, php, fancybox-3

I have this code in my search filter

```
<form action="<?php echo stm_listings_current_url() ?>" method="get" data-trigger="filter">
```

Here you can see

```
data-trigger="filter"
```

When i click on my filter, it opens opo up from fancybox with content [object Object]

Fancybox conflict

[image: Fancybox conflict]

This happens because fancybox opens on data-trigger too.

How can i fix this?

Comment: It would be better if you can post the full picture of your problem including the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to the latest version where `data-trigger` is replaced by `data-fancybox-trigger`